# Can multiple people trademark the same name?

Tags: copyright, trademark

I looked up a trademark on [TESS](http://tess2.uspto.gov/) and it turns out that it is already trademarked. This may sound like a noob question, but can I use it if my business is completely unrelated ? What if I own the domain, but someone else owned the trademark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, trademarks can be shared as long as they do not cause confusion.

For example,

Lexus the car
Lexis the information service
(Spelling is irrelevant in trademarks).

VAX a vacuum cleaner.
VAX a computer

Which worked well until the vacuum cleaner started running ads "The VAX sucks."

Answer (score 1):

Ace Bandages and Ace Hardware. Delta Faucets and Delta Airlines.

Since these are in unrelated industries, there is no confusion. So, there is no infringement.